# ST Smart Voice dev board (MK126V)

Tags: programming, st

I have some trouble with my ST MK126V3.

Is it possible to program the board with the ST-LINK/V2? I can't work out from the datasheet what debug interface is used and how to connect it properly.

Link to other datasheets/manuals will do the trick.

10x

Some link: [debugger](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00026748.pdf), [dev board](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00061574.pdf)

Comment: At the very least link to the board's manual/datasheet. It is hardly googleable.

Comment: yes, my point exactly. This is from the manufacturer: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF255176

Comment: As it turns out this is not uC. It is some sort of codec that is controlled over SPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chip on the board is not a uC. It is an IC that deals with the microphones and communicates over SPI with the uC.